# Accepting different image formats and uploading to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I am currently trying to send the images to Firebase via putString and the base64 encoded images. So far I am using FileSystem with Expo, and it spits out a base64 image that I can put into a decoder online and it shows the correct image, but when I try to upload it to Firebase storage it doesn't want to accept it as an image but rather just some data (not sure)? I assume the image is supposed to be a png as per the expo documentation even though the image is stored as a WebP on the simulator. (Expo on ReadAsStringAsync: "Read the entire contents of a file as a string. Binary will be returned in raw format, you will need to append data:image/png;base64, to use it as Base64.")

```
let uri = FileSystem.cacheDirectory + Date.now();
await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(uri, {intermediates: true});
await FileSystem.copyAsync({to: uri, from: image});
let base64Img = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync( uri, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });
let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
let imageName = `${this.props.user.id}_ProfilePhoto_${Date.now()}_${i}`;
let imageRef = storageRef.child("Profile Photos/" + imageName);
try {
 let base64 = "data:image/png;base64," + base64Img;
 console.log("Base 64: " + base64);
 const snapshot = await imageRef.putString(base64, "data_url", {
   contentType: "image/png"
 });
 const remoteURL = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
} catch (err) {
  alert(err);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you remove contentType: 'image/png'

Comment: Yeah I have tried removing it, and it says "Error Loading Preview". The upload is also way to small in size to be the image.